# Using a Calendar in a SharePoint Publishing Site?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, calendar, publishing-site

I've set up a publishing site for a project, but the calendar isn't available to me.
Anbody know how to make the default SP calendar available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: In each site, under "Site Settings", in the "Site Administration" column, click the "Site Features" link. Once the "Site Features" page loads, activate the "Team Collaborations Lists" feature.